# Lagrange Question

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Alice has only $24$ hours to study for an exam, and without preparation she will get $200$ points out of $1000$ points on the exam. It is estimated that her exam score will improve by $x(50−x)$ points if she reads her lecture notes for $x$ hours and $y(48−y)$ points if she solves review problems for y hours, but due to fatigue she will lose $(x+y)^2$ points. What is the maximum exam score she can obtain? Round your answer to the nearest integer.

I got $y=23/2$ and $x=25/2$.

When I plugged those back in I got $468.75$, and then I need to add the $200$ points. So my answer would be $668.75$ which would round to $669$. But this is not correct. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

the function you are inserted in is $f(x,y) = 200 +x(50-x) +y(48-y) - (x+y)^2$take the derivative for $x$ and $y$ and set is zero. This will give you the condition for a local extremum. The answer should be $x = 26/3,\ y = 23/3$. Then you still have to explain why that this is a local maximum and not a minimum. And at last you should check the global points.

The maximum test score is: $1802/3 \approx 600$

Comment: I still get that as a wrong answer

Comment: @user255048 It is the correct answer, see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maxima+200.+%2B+x*%2850.-x%29+%2B+y*%2848.-y%29+-+%28x%2By%29**2%2C+0%3Cx%2Cy%3C24)

Comment: thank you, maybe the grader is messed up, but it says that is wrong. But thank you!

Comment: is it possible the grader is looking for a percentage score?  I can see no other reason why this isn't the correct answer...

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

First of all (and most importantly), you call this a Lagrange problem (and your solution does satisfy x + y = 24), but is it really?  Seems improbable that the optimal strategy would involve no sleep.  I'd look in the interior, $x + y < 24$.

Second, I don't get the same numbers you get.  I get the same x and y values (using Lagrange, though these are not optimal), but not the same test score.  Are we using the same score function?  Mine is:
$$ 200+ x(50-x)+y(48-y)-(x+y)^2$$ Using the values you get from Lagrange, I see that as 512.5 .  Am I missing something?

Comment: I tried that before and it was wrong

Comment: Tried what before?  The interior?  setting the partials to 0 I get $x = \frac {26}{3}$ and $y = \frac {23}{3}$ same as the other posted answer.Gives a test score of 600.666...  Do you get a different test score?  Are we using the same score function?

Comment: I have tried 601 and still get a wrong answer

Comment: Sorry...I see no error.  I even tried doing it numerically, just looking at a mesh of points but I can't see any higher values.  Of course, I might have the wrong function but I note that the other posted answer matches the function (and all values) perfectly.  Doesn't prove we aren't making a common error but I sure don't see it.

Answer (score -1):

fx = 50-4x-2y and fy = 48-4y-2x

50-4x-2y=48-4y-2x

y=x-1

x+y=24 hours,
x+(x-1)=24
SO, x= 25/2

y= 24-25/2 = 23/2
...
f(25/2,23/2)= 200+(25/2)*(50−(25/2))+(23/2)(48−(23/2))−((25/2)+(23/2))^2
=512.5

IS IT CORRECT?